# VSCode Task to run various node commands

Tags: node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have a monorepo where I wish to create a script for starting up a specific project locally.

The project is completely `Node.js` based.

For me to set up this project locally for development, I need to run the following commands in this order:

1. Start up the docker images

   - `cd docker/dockerForTests`
   - `docker-compose up -d`
2. Start up the Web Auth server

   - `cd src/project/webAuthentication`
   - `setenvs projectAuthentication && npm start`
3. Start up the API

   - `cd src/project/api`
   - `setenvs projectAPI && npm start`
4. Start up the web client

   - `cd src/project/web`
   - `setenvs projectWeb && npm start`

I usually start each section up in a new terminal window, within VSCode, for ease of use.

To automate this process, I found out about VSCode Tasks.

Although it appears they are designed for 'building' or 'watching' tasks, I thought that I could modify the behavior to run the above commands for me.

Here was my attempt:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "runner": "terminal",
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Start Docker",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cd docker/dockerForTests && docker-compose up -d",
        },
        {
            "label": "Start Web Auth",
            "dependsOrder": "sequence",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "cd src/project/webAuthentication && setenvs projectAuthentiction && npm start"
        },
        {
            "label": "Start Up Local Development Environment",
            "presentation": {
                "echo": true,
                "reveal": "always",
                "focus": true,
                "panel": "new",
                "showReuseMessage": false,
                "clear": true
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "Start Docker",
                "Start Web Auth"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The first command works fine, but I wanted it to be like the integrated terminal, where it hangs for input once the command has finished running.

[image]

Secondly, the second task does not work as it's not a Node command.

I would like it to work like the regular, bash input.

[image]

How can I automate my above workflow? Is it even possible?

Comment: Is running server, api and web in containers could be ok for you, or do you only want to use vscode feature ?

Comment: @NicoM I'm not sure what you mean as containers. Basically, I just wanted to have the same as I'm doing manually. I.E. A new terminal window for each 'item', within VSCode

Answer (score 2):

At least for points 2, 3 and 4 [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) works fine, and it should work fine for point 1 as well. With following scripts in `scripts` section of package.json in your root directory you should be able to launch your dev env with just one command

```
"start-docker": "cd docker/dockerForTests && docker-compose up -d",
"start-auth": "cd src/project/webAuthentication && setenvs projectAuthentication && npm start",
"start-api": "cd src/project/api && setenvs projectAPI && npm start",
"start-client": "cd src/project/web && setenvs projectWeb && npm start",
"start-dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-docker\" \"npm run start-auth\" \"npm run start-api\" \"npm run start-client\""
```

This doesn't use VSCode task, but would simplify your life anyway.

Comment: Yes, I would say "it requires you to open a single terminal and let you running the 4 commands you need all in the same terminal"

Comment: That's a little unfortunate, as I was looking for something that would run each point separately, in a unique terminal

Comment: What "separately" means? Four running processes in the same terminal have to somehow share the only terminal for their output.

Comment: That's the thing, I need them to run in 4 separate terminals. Each command needs to have it's own terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add the necessary scripts to the root `package.json`'s `scripts` section. Once you do that, you should see them as VS Code tasks, thanks to VS Code's automatic task detection.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_task-autodetection for details.